# "Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing t he function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

am getting the below issue while using my custom component.

**Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing t
he function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol getValue in E:/AOT/systemjs-aot-16
62901741/src/**

**core.ts**

```
export function getValue(

 ):any{ return "";}
```

**cus-component.ts**

```
import { getValue } from './core.ts';
export let compTest = getValue();
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { compTest } from './cus-component';

 @NgModule({
 imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule,  RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: true })],
 declarations: [ HomeComponent,compTest ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more code. It's entirely unclear where this code is. Service, component, decorator, outside a class, ...

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: FYI `function f():any{ return "";}` is terrible

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but perhaps it solves your problem:

```
export function getValue() {
    () => '';
}
```